# No longer able to connecto to WPA wireless network.

Tags: wireless, networking

I used to connect to a wireless network at the place where I live providing a password using WPA (don't really know what that is), it's been a few months since I can't connect anymore, the problem is this:

when Ubuntu starts it sees the network but keeps asking for the password and doesn't connect. What could be the cause? The landlord did not change the access point password and he's using windows on his laptop and works fine.

I did not change any network configuration file on my system ...
Thank you so much.
Luca.

Comment: Try removing your wireless settings and set up everything again.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons why this could be happening. Have you looked at the Wireless Connection Wiki? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Connections

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to read that, though I was hoping for a little more specific answer...

Answer (score 0):

Get the same issue, however by deleting the access point from Ubuntu and reconnecting seems to work, though it takes ages to connect. I still can't find a proper solution either.

Comment: The WIKI page is outdated and half the files do not refer to Ubuntu 11.10...... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Connections

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.